# Printing Page Section using PrintJS on vueJS

Tags: vue.js, printjs

I have installed `printJS` on my vue project using `npm install print-js --save`

Print Preview is now successfully displaying but the problem is that it is printing the whole page together with the side panel and the scroll bars. I have implemented it like this:

```
<template>
  <b-modal>
     <div id="print-form">
       <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%" border="1px">
       </table>
        <button onclick="print()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Print</button>
     </div>
  </b-modal>
</template>

import * as Printjs from "print-js";
export default {
   method: {
     print() {
       Printjs({
         printable: "print-registration-form", //Id to print content 
         type: "HTML"
      });
    }
  }
}
```

When I click print, it will print the whole page and not the page section specified by the `id`. Is there a way I can only print the specific `div` content?

Comment: What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome and Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code! Was struggling getting this to work on Vue

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using the wrong id. Did you mean to use `print-form` instead?

```js
       printJS({
         printable: "print-form",
         type: "HTML"
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

I can propose you this solution:

```css
@media print { 
  body * { 
  visibility: hidden; 
  } 
  #targetDiv, #targetDiv * { 
  visibility: visible; border: none; 
  }
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html> 
 <body> 
  <h2>The window.print() Method</h2> 
  <div>
    <p>Click the button to print the current page.</p> 
  </div>
  
  <div id="targetDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum kjng kq fev lnb fesl</p>   
  </div>
  <button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button> 
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: Tried using your solution. It eliminated the scrollbars but it still displays the left panel and the other sections. It should be the table content alone. But thanks to your suggestion!