# How to pass HTML to JPG/PNG? In Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How can i convert an HTML to a JPG/PNG image? I already tried various options but none works for me, they only make the image of some parts of the HTML.

**Example with html2canvas:**

**TS**

```
capturar() {
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="capture">
    <ion-grid class="grid-padding-info-verde">
      <ion-row class="row-info">

        <ion-col size="12">
          <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle" class="check-icono"></ion-icon>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col size="12" class="info-col">
          <span class="trans-sub"> {{ this.fecha }}</span>
        </ion-col>

      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</div>
```

This error I get when I use the example: [image]

"DOMException: Failed to set the 'adoptedStyleSheets' property on 'ShadowRoot': Sharing constructed stylesheets in multiple documents is not allowed"

Do you know any other tools?
Basically I need to take a screenshot of only a part of my screen not the full screen. Any ideas?

Comment: you don't have to pass `document.body`. try passing `document.querySelector('#your-id')` or use the ElementRef of an angular component you want to take a screenshot of (in case you're using angular 2)

Comment: Using ```document.querySelector ('# your-id')``` I also get the error: "DOMException: Failed to set the 'adoptedStyleSheets' property on 'ShadowRoot': Sharing constructed stylesheets in multiple documents is not allowed"

Comment: did you make sure that your selector in `document.querySelector('...')` actually returns an element? If so you should probably just google the exact error...

Comment: If you have problem with thml2canvas, you can try my alternative solution with windows.print() https://stackoverflow.com/a/65885971/12305715

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image

In your page:

```
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';

capturar(){
    var node = document.getElementById('capture');
    var options = {quality: 1};

    domtoimage.toJpeg(node, options).then((dataUrl) => {
      console.log(dataUrl) //Image in base64 jpeg
    });
}
```

Comment: I've used and I guarantee it work like a charm. But it has some issues on blurry images and HD renderings.

https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image/issues/69#issuecomment-486146688

Comment: A git repo with the script and some fixes
https://github.com/rafaeldcastro/dom-to-image-hd-fix